# Possible to allow user interaction to display node in SCNScene Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am beginner at scene kit and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the apple documentation.

Edit:

My question isn't clear, maybe if I explain what I want to happen it will help.

I want the user to tap the view and then inside the scene new nodes appear. I want the user to be allowed to tap wherever in the scene/view they wish, and then the nodes appear.

I have two files. One is a UIViewController, setting the self.view to a SCNView. when i set the view.scene = SceneFile(), the scene loads over the entire view.

In the view controller I have a function tap recognizer. The SceneFile currently does not contain any of the new nodes (e.g. hydrogen bonds) which I wish to display when the user taps twice on the scene.

So in summary, I want my hydrogen bonds to display when the view controller recognizes the UITapGesture.

I am not bound to having the code for the tap in the view controller, if there is a way to allow user interaction (taps) in the SCNScene file and from there create a function that adds the hydrogen bonds to the scene when the user taps.

Do I add the nodes in the scene and then unhide them from the scene in the view controller tap function when the user taps? Or is there a way to enable user interaction in the scene and then when the tap occurs, the nodes appear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an array of SCNNode in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495667/how-to-create-an-array-of-scnnode-in-swift)

Comment: what do you mean by "function inside the `SCNScene`"? Is that a method in a subclass?

Comment: I found a question that actually helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444524/scenekit-detecting-user-tapped-object

Comment: Hydrogen bonds... Is *everyone's* first SceneKit app some kind of molecule viewer?